# How to set asymmetric pageMargin on ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need the ability to dynamically set a different left margin and right margin on a ViewPager.

The picture below shows that currently one card is slightly visible to the left and one card is slightly visible to the right. In certain cases, I want to be able to somehow increase the margin on the left side only to cause the card to the left to not be rendered until the user swipes it into view.

[image: Current Behavior - both margins are equal]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to wrap my CardView in a FrameLayout. That allowed me to dynamically set the margin layout params on the card view and "hide" a card from sight.